# Isolating a relationship's significance

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, variance, interpretation, regression-coefficients

The thought experiment:

STEM = having a science, technology, engineering or mathematics degree (0/1), W = wages in the top quartile (0/1), LOC = individual location vector (integer values 1-20 representing different cities)

1. When we regress W on STEM (reg w STEM), we find that the coefficient on STEM is positive
2. When we regress W on STEM and LOC (reg W STEM LOC1 LOC2 ... LOC20), we find the coefficient on STEM is less positive
3. When we regress STEM on LOC (reg STEM LOC1 LOC2 ... LOC20), we find that the coefficients on some LOC are positive and some are negative
4. When we regress W and LOC (reg W LOC1 LOC2 ... LOC20), we find that the coefficients on some LOC are positive and some are negative

Q1) How can discuss the amount of the relationship between W = 1 and STEM = 1 that is due to STEM = 1 versus the fact that people with STEM = 1 may choose to live in locations (LOC) where W is more likely to be 1 and avoid locations where W is less likely to be 1?

Q2) What models, model output, and/or post estimation commands help create a more comprehensive story?

Comment: What is your causal model of how these variables relate to each other? And what exactly are you interested in?

Comment: I want to explain how much of the estimate STEM is causal on W versus proxying for other observed covaries that are related to STEM and W (here, LOC). I used this example for simplicity. You can imagine that the causal relationship of interest is Y (wages above) and X (STEM above) and a want to explain how much of the naive Y on X is also due to other observables Z (location above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your dependent variable (W) is Binary, you could consider the **Logistic Regression approach**. The Logistic Regression coefficients are in terms of log-odds and you can easily derive the odds or probabilities from these coefficients.

Logistic Regression allows you to estimate **Marginal Effects**. These can help you understand the effect of STEM on the probability of W (having wages in the top quartile). For example in Stata software, you can easily accomplish this using "**mfx**" command after logistic regression.

The interpretation of marginal effects is the change in probability of W if the individual has a STEM degree. Suppose the marginal effect of STEM is estimated to be 0.2, it means that the probability of having Wages in the top quartile increases by 0.2 if the individual has a STEM degree.

For locations, you could consider including dummy variables for locations. The upside of this is that you can estimate the marginal effects/probabilities and their effects on W for each location separately. The downside is that it will introduce a lot of coefficients in your model and restrict degrees of freedom. You will need a bigger dataset for this.

Comment: With this approach, is it just telling you the effect of STEM on W across the average LOC? Instead, I want to isolate the effect of W when we account for the relationship between W and LOC. I.E., account for the sorting effect

Comment: @CJ12 If you include dummy variables for locations, they will account for the effects of each location on W. So, you will be isolating the effect of STEM as well as the effect of each location on W. This means that you will have a separate coefficient and marginal effect of each location on W along with the effect of STEM on W.

Comment: so the marginal effect of black with all else at average is the "causal" effect of black on wage accounting for any sorting of individuals to locations (or other controls)?

Comment: all other variables staying constant at average, the marginal effect of black will show the change in probability of W (having top quartile wages) if black = 1 (instead of 0). The other variables including locations can be interpreted in the same way. Logistic regression and marginal effects deal with probabilities.

Comment: To be clear. If I ran in Stata, logit W STEM i.LOC and then mfx the coefficient on STEM would be the causal effect of STEM on W. Importantly, it would take into account the sorting effect between STEM and LOC?

Comment: The dummies for LOC should take care of sorting and other effects related to locations. Whether the effect of STEM is "causal" or not, may depend on some theory/background to back up the significance of the STEM coefficient.